# SQL: Can this be written more efficiently?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I want to create a temp table to hold unique gid values from a number of different tables that all share this common gid. I currently have this written as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE #QHP_Unique
(some_gid INT)  

INSERT INTO #QHP_Unique
SELECT DISTINCT PR.some_gid
FROM Table_PR PR

INSERT INTO #QHP_Unique
SELECT DISTINCT PX.some_gid
FROM Table_PX PX
LEFT OUTER JOIN #QHP_Unique QS ON PX.some_gid= QS.some_gid
WHERE QS.some_gid IS NULL;

INSERT INTO #QHP_Unique
SELECT DISTINCT COP.some_gid
FROM Table_COP COP
LEFT OUTER JOIN #QHP_Unique QS ON COP.some_gid= QS.some_gid
WHERE QS.some_gid IS NULL;
```

and 3 more of these INSERTS with 3 other tables.

Is there a way to write all of this in a single query?

Comment: Combine all `SELECTs` with UNION. `UNION` returns distinct results so there's no need for `DISTINCT`

Answer (score 4):

You can do it using `UNION`, it will pick `DISTINCT` values from combined tables:

```
CREATE TABLE #QHP_Unique
(some_gid INT)  

INSERT INTO #QHP_Unique (some_gid)
SELECT some_gid
FROM Table_PR

UNION 

SELECT some_gid
FROM Table_PX 

UNION 

SELECT some_gid
FROM Table_COP
```

Comment: If you use union, you would remove duplicates, so it should be union all on these

Comment: Sperick looks for distinct values, UNION is a proper solution to the problem.